# Add SQL file to BI solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, t-sql, reporting-services

I am working on SSRS BI projects.
Using VS 2010 in combination with TFS 2010 I create solutions.
Each solution contains one or more Report Server Projects.
Each project contains one or more reports.
Each report uses one or more Datasets, always based on T-SQL.
The SQL in those datasets is horrible to read, therefore I would like to add the original .sql file to the applicable project. Is this possible? How? Adding a SQL Server project to my solutions seems like too big a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add an existing item. If it's a valid SQL file it should be able to be added to the project so TFS will pick it up when you do the check-in.

Comment: It does, but as soon as I try to open it in VS21010 VS2010 crashes without any notification or error, it just disapperas of the screen and I have to restart VS2010. The file will be visible but as soon as I open it VS2010 goes down without as much as a whimp. Same goes for all others trying to open that file, regardless of who added it... This behaviour was observed on 4 machines running 3 different OS-es (2 Windows 7 flavours, one Win8 machine)

Comment: Can you open the SQL file in SSMS? Can you still open the original SSRS BI project?

Comment: I will try that and let you know